# Issue of syntax in UNIX

Tags: unix, cygwin

I try this command but it sends error

```
$ vcp -accepthostkeys -pw "aRXdxD6xrFeVQcva" "VALIDATION_30638_1.zip" "ACOE_PPM_Admintest@p04r7p0w1488***:220***:F:/ITG/transfers/VALIDATION_30638_1.zip"
```

But i change the :220 to #220. it worked.

```
$ vcp -accepthostkeys -pw "aRXdxD6xrFeVQcva" "VALIDATION_30638_1.zip" "ACOE_PPM_Admintest@p04r7p0w1488***#220***:F:/ITG/transfers/VALIDATION_30638_1.zip"
```

2. Is there a way that we can use # instead of : in specifying a port number?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the output error in your question and explain what are you trying to do with your command. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In addition to Franck suggestion, what is vcp and from where is coming from ? It is not part of a cygwin package.